# rails7 stimulus and datatables initialized twice

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datatables, turbolinks, ruby-on-rails-7, stimulusjs

When I prepare DataTable in stimulus controller, it fires twice what is behaviour of turbo (for caching purposes) and therefore I get DataTables error of initializing it twice

When I tried fix as I use in rails6 without stimulus, it does not work

```
document.addEventListener('turbo:before-cache', function() {
     if ($('#invoices_wrapper').length ==1) {invoicetable.destroy() ;} });
```

If I put console.log inside that function, I see it is not even executed.
How can I properly setup DataTables with stimulus?

This is my code

```
import { Controller } from "@hotwired/stimulus"
import $ from 'jquery';

import 'jszip';
import datatable from 'datatables.net-bs5';
import 'datatables.net-buttons-bs5';

window.datatable = datatable();

export default class extends Controller {
  connect() {

      var invoicetable = $('#invoices').DataTable({
      
      'order': [1, 'asc'],
      'serverSide': true,
      "processing": true,
      'ajax' : '/invoices.json',
      columns: [
      //{data: 'id', searchable: false, orderable: false},
        {data: 'name' },
        {data: 'value' }        
      ],
      initComplete: function ()
            {
             console.log("done")
        }
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: did you ever get anywhere with this?

Comment: @JakeMcAllister nope, I use turbo frames and pagy for fast tables instead because I was not able to solve this

Comment: It's exactly what i've ended up doing ha! Such a better development experience :)

Comment: Thanks. I am soooooo tired of the datatables timewasting. in 30 minutes replaced 2 datatables with pagy and turboframes. Amazing.